# How can I add multiple rows to a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, dataextensions, upsert

Currently, I have a microsite which is being used as a form to insert / update data in a data extension.

In data extension, email is NOT a primary key so I can have multiple records for same email because I have a column called "Group". So 1@1.com can exist more than once in the data extension with GroupA, GroupB and GroupC as 3 different rows.

Here is the code / AMPScript

I open the contact / row details like this:

```
%%[
var @DEColumnEmail, @DEColumnFirstName, @DEColumnLastName, @DEColumnGroup
set @row = row(@rows,@i)
set @DEColumnEmail = field(@row,"Email")
set @DEColumnFirstName = field(@row,"First Name")
set @DEColumnLastName = field(@row,"Last Name")
set @DEColumnGroup = field(@row,"Group")
]%%

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="%%=v(@DEColumnEmail)=%%"><br/>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="%%=v(@DEColumnFirstName)=%%"><br/>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="%%=v(@DEColumnLastName)=%%"><br/>
<input type="text" name="Group" id="Group" value="%%=v(@DEColumnGroup)=%%">
```

Then to update the record, I use another page where I pass on the values and run UpsertDE AMPScript like this

```
SET @Email_Address = RequestParameter("email")  
SET @First_Name = RequestParameter("fname")
SET @Last_Name = RequestParameter("lname")
SET @Group = RequestParameter("Group")

IF IsEmailAddress(@Email_Address) THEN
    /* Add/update the record to the appropriate DE */   
    UpsertDE("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME",1,"Email",@Email_Address,"First Name",@First_Name,"Last Name",@Last_Name,"Group",@Group)
ENDIF

/* Redirect to the confirmation page */     
Redirect(@RedirectURL)

ELSE

    /* The text below will be displayed in case of error */ 
    SET @ErrorMessage = "There was an error in your submission. Please return to the previous page and try again."

ENDIF
```

The limitation of this approach is that, I am only able to update / add one row at a time. I would like to add the record and if there are more Groups then I want to insert / update record just once instead of 3 manual steps.

For group, I want to display checkbox list like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Group" value="GroupA"> GroupA<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Group" value="GroupB"> GroupB<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Group" value="GroupC"> GroupB<br>
```

And based on the selected values, 1, 2 or 3 rows should be added / updated in the data extension.

Any advice on what should be my approach or how my code / AMPScript should look look?

Comment: You would need to loop through the values passed in Group and preform 3 separate upserts.  You should be getting a single comma delimited value from RequestParameter("Group").  Is that Correct?

Comment: Thank you - Could you please show me with an example how to do this?

Comment: Can you output the value in @Group?  example:  %%=v(@Group)=%%

Comment: @l-k, please don't expect everyone to write the code for you.  Update your question as you work through it or post another specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

- Create a rowset with all the records that match the email.
- Then count number of records in the rowset.
- Create a loop that iterates from 1 to the number of records.
- In each iteration you can update a single record.

---

```
%%[

set @Set_of_rows = Lookuprows ("Data_extension_City","State","Texas")

set @Number_of_rows= RowCount(@Set_of_rows)

FOR @i = 1 TO @Number_of_rows DO

  SET @row = Row(@Set_of_rows,@i)
  SET @id = Field(@row,"ID")
  SET @name = Field(@row,"Name")
  SET @ud =UpdateDE("Data_extension_city",1,"ID",@id,"Counter",@i)

NEXT @i

]%%
```

In this example the data extension is updated, the field counter is filled with a sequential number. It is supposed that the DE has a field called ID, City, State and a counter. Only rows from Texas are updated. The example is meaningless but shows the process.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you be able to help me with the code/ampscript? OR how can I update my code above to accomplish the requirement?